# Using mod_rewrite to send all requests to a certain document

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to temporarily redirect all requests for a site to `index.html`, using Apache only. Is this mod_rewrite approach going to work, and is it the right way to do it?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^.*$  /index.html  [R]
```

Comment: I think you should use [R=302] to specify it is temporary.

Comment: @pritaeas Note that `R` and `R=302` are the same. Apache defaults to a 302 unless stated otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use something like this I think:

```
RewriteRule !^/index.html$  /index.html [R=302]
```

Like pritaeas noted, you should use the 302 code to specify that the move is temporary. And you want to match everything *but* `/index.html`, otherwise you'll send the browser on an infinite redirect loop.

Also, if you have any images, stylesheets, JS files, or other resources that are in the same directory or subdirectory, you need to also make exceptions for those or turn the rewrite engine off in those directories.